# Ogr: How to add layer description to dgn?

Tags: c#, ogr, layers, dgn

I have created a dgn-file using Ogr, but can't find a way to fill out the description for this layer programatically. (something like _dgnLayer.Description = "Highways")

```
opts.Add("SEED=" + seedfile);
opts.Add("COPY_WHOLE_SEED_FILE=YES");

// Prepare
Initialization.PrepareGDAL();

// Initialize output DGN
using (var dgnDriver = Ogr.GetDriverByName("DGN"))
{
    _dgnDataSource = dgnDriver.CreateDataSource(filename, opts.ToArray());
    _dgnLayer = _dgnDataSource.CreateLayer("", null, wkbGeometryType.wkbUnknown, null);
    _dgnFeatureDefinition = _dgnLayer.GetLayerDefn();
    _dgnFeatureDefinition.AddFieldDefn(new FieldDefn("ErrorTest", FieldType.OFTString));
}
```